# is it possible to insert microsoft word document editor to own application using PIA

Tags: c#, pia, primary-interop-assembly

How to use Office Primary Interop assembly in own application like [Business in the box](http://www.envision-sbs.com/).  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host Microsoft Office applications inside a control using the [DSO Framer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311765). You simply :

- Add a reference to DSOFramer COM dll.
- Right-click on your Toolbox in Visual Studio -> Choose Items -> COM Components -> DSO Gramer Control Object
- Drag a new DSO Framer on to your form or parent control
- And call `framerControl.Open(@"C:\SomeDocument.doc");` - it will work out which Office application to embed.

---

Alternatively you can use the Win32 API to [embed other programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-program/758772#758772) into a Panel control inside your own application.