# run a foreign exe inside a windows form app

Tags: c#

i have a c# powered windows form app and i want to run a exe inside it. that program is another seperate executable file. lets say that that exe is not a dot net app, but written in another language, does it matter ?

so i would want that program to lie inside my winforms, how can i do it?? Also, can i place it anywhere in the winforms? are there like properties already included by default? thanks. hage u tried doing these? if so what are the steps to take? thank you stackoverflow for making a nice  developer community. i really cherish this

Comment: Setting a name wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I run another application within a panel of my C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-sharp-program)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by PInvoking `SetParent()`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

First you need to start the third party application within your application:

```
var clientApplication = Process.Start("PATH_TO_YOUR_EXECUTABLE");
```

then set its `MainWindowHandle` to your main window handle:

```
SetParent(clientApplication.MainWindowHandle, YourMainWindowOrAContainerControl.Handle);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);    

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Process p = Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Reference to fardjad but it can only run small programs like notepad, firefox, safari