# Add JPanel to JFrame from another project

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to make a program where I can add something like "plug-ins". Lets say I have `Project1` where I have `JFrame` and `Project2` where I have `JPanel`.

The point is, that user can develop his own programs (plug-ins) and than add it to the main program (`Project1`).

So... I export frame as runnable JAR file and export panel as runnable JAR file (or only as JAR file?).

What I want to do is to show panel in frame.

Simply I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762379/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-windows-form-app) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6GWgxEvibE) but only in Java and with panel, I don't need to run any .exe programs. (It's going to run on Linux not Windows).

My professional picture that should describe what I want to do :) 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFl6e.png)

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the plugin part, you can look at [this project](https://github.com/Paragoumba/OnlineServices/blob/master/OnlineServicesServer/src/fr/paragoumba/onlineservices/server/CommandInterpreter.java) that I created, the loadPlugin method loads plugins from jar files.

And for the JPanel part, you just have to let to plugins a way (an API surely) that lets them change the displayed panel of the JFrame (with [JFrame::setContentPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container))).
I hope that'll help you, ask me for more precision if you need.

**Edit:**

As an example you can get the JPanel from the .jar and instantiate it like this :

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
String packageName = "package.where.is.the.jpanel.to.load";
JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) Class.forName(packageName, true, classLoader).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer.
I dont exactly know how to make that JPanel. 
I cant find any JFrame::setContentView method. But maybe JFrame::getContentPanel is the same? Lets say that I add plugin to my server and I need to show JPanel in my JFrame? Can you show me some code how to do that?

Comment: Oops sorry it's [setContentPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container))

Comment: But I know the instance of JFrame, because that is my main program. 
I run JFrame and then JFrame runs .jar file (from another folder) where is JPanel. So I need to get instance of JPanel and do something like
JPanel jPanel = instance.
But I dont need to call some methods from JPanel or something, just need to put it in some area (like in that video that I linked), so user cant move it or something... And when user click button, JPanel will show up or hide.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example that shows you how to instantiate a custom JPanel from a plugin