# Docking an Mainframe .exe in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mainframe

how to dock a mainframe .exe in a windows form or bring to front and place it on panel.I tried the following link [Docking Window inside another Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836176/docking-window-inside-another-window/5965992#5965992) .It is working for all application like notepad, task Manager etc.But it is not working for Mainframe application.

Thanks

Comment: I presume you are trying to dock a Terminal emulator; if so which terminal emulator and have you looked at the appropriate manual / Googled it yet ???. Unless you tell us what application you are trying to dock, I doubt any one can help you

Comment: yes correct , we are trying to dock Terminal emulator.

Comment: Terminal emulator 14

Comment: Is 14 really the name of the "Terminal Emulator" is it the version number ???. If it is Version 14, it could be Reflection. Also is the Emulator running under citrix ???

Comment: Yes it is reflection running under citrix.

Comment: Are you able to dock other applications running under citrix?

Comment: No unable to dock app undex citrix, but can able to dock all other applications.

Comment: As you are unable to dock other citrix applications, perhaps this has nothing to do with it being a mainframe emulator and instead has everything to do with it being a citrix application.

Comment: I can able to dock even CMD Prompt in citrix but i cant dock some application running under citrix.