# How can I take over, another running application within a panel of my C# program?

Tags: c#, process, take, setparent

What i'm trying to do is to take over another running application and attach it to a panel in my Form, somthing like this:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }
```

but in  my case i won't Start the app, i will have to take over existing, running process.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: Your code workks fine here. You will need to move the process to the origin of your panel.. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836176/docking-window-inside-another-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "notepad")
    // or
    //if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Untitled - Notepad")
    {
        SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }
};
```