# How can I control another application within a panel of a C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, exe

I have been reading lots on how to hosting exe Applications in a WinForm project. And I have read these articles and successfully run the Windows Journal application in a panel.
[How can I run another application within a panel of my C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-sharp-program)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project

However, I also intend to make Windows Journal open a exist .jnt file when click a button. And when the application be closed, automatically save the file.
Is that possible to control Journal application to open and save files from its parent winform application?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into MDI Forms - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C

Comment: Thanks... I wish to have a file open by Windows Journal, which is embedded in a C# application, is that possible?