# Embed Exe in Winform c# application: Mouse click not working on menustrip and toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, embed

I have created a simple Winform C# application (.exe) in VS 2010 with Menustrip and Toolstrip.

Now I have embedded this application in another Winform application using the following code.

The problem is I can't click on MenuItem or Toolstrip buttons in the embedded application. Alt+F or keyboard shortcuts are working but no mouse clicks are working on menu or toolstrip items. Thank you for your reply.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("C:\\NewFolder\\myapplication.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Rather than

```
    Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Found here: [How can I run another application within a panel of my C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-sharp-program) (includes lots more helpful stuff)