# Is there a way to start program in control in c# windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a multi tool in windows forms where i can run an program in an control. not external (that it opens (not Process.Start("program.exe")), that it runs in the control in my multi tool.
Is there a way to do it maybe like this or something?:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
process.Start();
control.Process = process; // execute process in control
```

i dont have any ideas, internet doesnt gives answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run another application within a panel of my C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-sharp-program)

Comment: What does “in control” mean in your context? If you cannot describe that clearly in words or drawings, I don’t think an answer can be there.